# How to import legacy JavaScript modules / AMD modules in ES6?

Tags: ecmascript-6, requirejs, es6-modules

How to import legacy JavaScript modules / AMD modules in ES6?

In this context,
Legacy module means: module which pollute global namespace
AMD module means: module which work with require.js

Is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: For legacy module, I tried just call it like import {foo} from "./bar" but this not works.
For AMD, no idea.

Comment: What would be the content of a "legacy module"? Can you post an example?

Comment: E.g. jquery.
What I tried is something like import {$} from './js/jquery.min' but this not works.